# pdf how to batch list pdf having annotations? qpdf? pdfinfo?

Tags: pdf, annotations, qpdf

I was surprised when I printed a pdf which I annotated with Okular that print was without the annotations eventhough it does show on the screen.
I have to save the annoted file as printed pdf, then print it.

Question:
how can I list all pdfs having at least one annotation on at least one page?

Apparently, pdfinfo returns Acroform when there is an annotation

```
            find -type f -iname "*.pdf" -exec pdfinfo {} \;
```

but does not displays the filename.

I'm not familiar with qpdf, but it does not seem to provide this info

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `bash -c 'echo {}; pdfinfo {}` for the find's exec argument?

Answer (score 1):

Using `pdfinfo` from [poppler-utils](/questions/tagged/poppler-utils) you can say,

```shell
find . -type f -iname '*.pdf' | while read -r pn
do  pdfinfo "$pn" |
    grep -q '^Form: *AcroForm' && printf '%s\n' "$pn"
done
```

to list the names of PDF files for which `pdfinfo` reports:

```
Form:           AcroForm
```

However, in my tests it misses several PDFs with text annotations
and lists several without so I'd avoid it for this job. Below are 2
alternatives: `qpdf` supports all annotation subtypes,
`python3-poppler-qt5` only a subset but can be much faster.

(For a non-POSIX shell adapt the commands in this posting.)

**EDIT**: `find` constructs edited to avoid unsafe and GNU-reliant `{}`s.

---

[qpdf](/questions/tagged/qpdf) versions since 8.3.0 support a [json](/questions/tagged/json) representation
of non-content PDF data, and if you're on a system with the [jq](/questions/tagged/jq)
JSON processor you can list unique PDF annotation types as
tab-separated values (in this case discarding the output and using
the exit code only):

```shell
find . -type f -iname '*.pdf' | while read -r pn
do  qpdf --json --no-warn -- "$pn" |
    jq -e -r --arg typls '*' -f annots.jq > /dev/null && 
    printf '%s\n' "$pn"
done
```

where

- `--arg typls '*'` specifies desired annotation subtypes, e.g. `*`
  for all (the default), or `Text,FreeText,Link` for a selection
- `-e` sets exit code 4 if no output was made (no annotations found)
- `-r` produces raw (non-JSON) output
- the `jq` script file `annots.jq` contains the following

```jq
#! /usr/bin/env jq-1.6
def annots:
    ( if ($typls | length) > 0 and $typls != "*"
      then $typls
      else
        # annotation types, per Adobe`s PDF Reference 1.7 (table 8.20)
        "Text,Link,FreeText,Line,Square,Circle,Polygon"
        + ",PolyLine,Highlight,Underline,Squiggly,StrikeOut"
        + ",Stamp,Caret,Ink,Popup,FileAttachment,Sound,Movie"
        + ",Widget,Screen,PrinterMark,TrapNet,Watermark,3D"
      end | split(",")
    ) as $whitelist
    | .objects
    | .[]
    | objects
    | select( ."/Type" == "/Annot" )
    | select( ."/Subtype" | .[1:] | IN($whitelist[]) )
    | ."/Subtype" | .[1:]
    ;
[ annots ] | unique as $out
| if ($out | length) > 0 then ($out | @tsv) else empty end
```

---

For many purposes it's tempting to use [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) with
[python3-poppler-qt5](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/python3-poppler-qt5)
to handle the entire file list in one go,

```shell
find . -type f -iname '*.pdf' -exec python3 path/to/script -t 1,7 {} '+'
```

where the `-t` option lists the desired annotation subtypes, per
[poppler documentation](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/api/qt5/classPoppler_1_1Annotation.html);
1 is `AText` and 7 is `ALink`. Without `-t` all subtypes known to
poppler (0 through 14) are selected, i.e. not all existing subtypes
are supported.

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3.8
import popplerqt5

def gotAnnot(pdfPathname, subtypls):
    pdoc = popplerqt5.Poppler.Document.load(pdfPathname)
    for pgindex in range(pdoc.numPages()):
        annls = pdoc.page(pgindex).annotations()
        if annls is not None and len(annls) > 0:
            for a in annls:
                if a.subType() in subtypls:
                    return True
    return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys, getopt
    typls = range(14+1)         ## default: all subtypes
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "t:")
    for o, a in opts:
        if o == "-t" and a != "*":
            typls = [int(c) for c in a.split(",")]
    for pathnm in args:
        if gotAnnot(pathnm, typls):
            print(pathnm)
```